# How can I divide the elements in the 2nd column of a table by given number?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I build a table of pairs like so.

```
table = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, a, b, c}]
```

After getting `table`, I want to derive `table1` from it, by dividing for the 2nd element in each pair by 25, so that `table1` is equivalent to

```
Table[{x, f[x]/25}, {x, a, b, c}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `MapAt[#/25 &, table, {All, 2}]` or `table.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]`.

Comment: Also, `{#1, #2/25} & @@@ table`

Comment: data2 = data  /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y/2}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's get the comments on record as an answer.

J.M.

```
 MapAt[#/25 &, table, {All, 2}]
 table.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]
```

m_goldberg

```
{#1, #2/25} & @@@ table
```

Alucard

```
table /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y/25}
```

---

Timing analysis: 
**Update**
it turned out the previous barchart was wrong

```
  table = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^7, 2}];
fun1[x_List] := MapAt[#/25 &, x, {All, 2}]
fun2[x_List] := x.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]
fun3[x_List] := {#1.#2/25} & @@@ table
fun4[x_List] := Module[{table1 = x}, table1[[All, 2]] /= 25.; table1]
fun[x_List] := x /. {p_, y_} -> {p, y/25}
BarChart[{RepeatedTiming[fun1[data]][[1]], 
  RepeatedTiming[fun2[table]][[1]], RepeatedTiming[fun3[table]][[1]], 
  RepeatedTiming[fun[table]][[1]], RepeatedTiming[fun4[table]][[1]] }, 
 ChartLabels -> {"J.M. 1", "J.M.2", "m_goldberg", "Alucard", 
   "Schumacher"}]
```

[image: barchart with absolutetimings]

Comment: i made a simple barchart with the absolute timings, just to see which solution was faster. the results says that the faster solution is the second one posted by J.M. (  table.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]), while the third one is the slowest, the other 2 are equal

Comment: @Alucard, since this post is CW, please edit this to include your `BarChart[]` and any code you used for testing. You might also consider using `RepeatedTiming[]`.

Comment: @J.M.  what does it mean CW?

Comment: @Alucard, [community wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

Comment: @J.M oh i didn't see your suggestion before, i tried with RepeatedTiming too, the barchart doesn't change much. Should i update the post with the new code?

Comment: @Alucard, maybe it does not matter then, if so; as can be ascertained from the function's name, `RepeatedTiming[]` does multiple trials and then averages the results, as opposed to the one evaluation done by `Timing[]`/`AbsoluteTiming[]`. It's up to you.

Comment: For matrices with many columns, the following should be even more efficient than the solution by @J.M.: `fun4[x_List] := Module[{table1 = x}, table1[[All, 2]] /= 25.; table1]`

Comment: In addition, `Inner` variations on J.M's solution, `funx[x_List] := Inner[Times, x, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]]` and  `funy[x_List] := Inner[Times, x, {1, 1/25}, List]` are very significantly slower.  (Both at least 50x slower on my machine). `Dot` appears to be very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Somethings is wrong with the timings in the other answer.  Here is what `BenchmarkPlot` in the GeneralUtilites package gives.

```
fun1[x_List] := MapAt[#/25 &, x, {All, 2}]
fun2[x_List] := x.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/25}]
fun3[x_List] := {#1, #2/25} & @@@ x
fun4[x_List] := Module[{table1 = x}, table1[[All, 2]] /= 25.; table1]
fun[x_List] := x /. {p_, y_} :> {p, y/25}

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
BenchmarkPlot[{fun, fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4}, RandomReal[9, {#, 2}] &]
```

[image]

Comment: ah now i see the error, when i added schumacher's method i changed the name of the list from data to table1 and i forgot to update the rest of the code!

Comment: That `fun3`... that should be a comma and not a dot.